# Why Spreadsheet::XLSX parses dates inconsistently on different machines?

Tags: excel, perl

I created a Perl script reading information from an XLSX sheet. Since on one machine it worked well, and on another it did not, I included a short debug section:

```
$sheetdate = ($sheet -> {Cells} [0] [$sheet->{MaxCol}]) -> value();
print "value: $sheetdate\n";
$sheetdate = ($sheet -> {Cells} [0] [$sheet->{MaxCol}]) -> get_format();
print "getformat: $sheetdate\n";
```

On one machine it printed:

```
value: 2016-01-18
getformat: yyyy-mm-dd
```

While on the other:

```
value: 1-18-16
getformat: m-d-yy
```

Same script, same worksheet, different results. I believe that something in the environment makes the difference, but I do not know what exactly.

Any hints?

Comment: Where is `get_format()` coming from? Can't find it in the `Spreadsheet::XSLX` docs.

Comment: get_format is in package Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell. I have not figured out yet, but I guess it's one of dependencies, as I have not explicitly installed this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem was an outdated Spreadsheet::XLSX cpan module installed as RPM from the distribution repository. The RPM included version 0.13 of this module, in CPAN there was already version 0.15, and since version 0.14 the module's behaviour was changed in this particular respect. So once I replaced the pre-compiled module with the version downloaded directly from CPAN and compiled locally, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

*"Same script, same worksheet, different results.  I believe that something in the environment makes the difference, but I don not know what exactly."*

You sort-of indicate here yourself that you're not really seeking the solution to a perl or XLSX problem so much as some assistance with troubleshooting your environment.

Without access to the environment its difficult to offer a solution per se, but I can say this - you need to;

1) Re-arrange things so that you *do* get the same result from both environments;

2) Identify a list of differences between the original, problem environment and the one that now "works"; and

3) Modify one thing on the list at a time - moving towards the environment that works - checking each time until it becomes clear what the key variable (not in a programming sense) is.

With regards to (1), take a look at [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).  Using Strawberry, its relatively easy to set up what some call *Perl on a stick* (see [Portable ZIP edition](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html)) - a complete perl environment on a USB stick.  Put your document on the same USB and then try the two environments - this time with absolute certainty of having the same environment.  If different results persist, try booting from a "live environement" DVD (linux or widows as appropriate), and then using the USB.

Ultimately, I'd suggest there's something (such as a spreadsheet template ) at play that *is* different between the environments.  You just need to go through a process of elimination to find out what it is.

Comment: I understand that it's next to impossible to diagnose someone else's environment. I posted the question hoping that someone else might have encountered the same or a similar problem and solved it successfully.

Comment: Thank you for the Strawberry Perl hint - I will give it a try.

Comment: You probably already know this - but the values being different is not surprising - it's merely a consequence of the format being different.  The comment about a spreadsheet template "pre-setting" the format wasn't just a throw away line.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that the different results result from different formats - that's why I decided to check the formats in the first place. ;) 

The issue is however, **why** the same file (I even checked md5 sums) presents different date formats on two different machines.
To add insult to injury, if I read -> {val} instead of value() (it's deprecated, isn't it?) , on one machine a properly formatted date string is returned, while on the other - the number of days since the beginning of the Excel epoch - as if it simply ignored the date format.

Comment: Can you `use Data::Dumper` and post the output from `my $cell = $sheet -> {Cells} [0] [$sheet->{MaxCol}];  print Dumper($cell); ` for each machine  ?

Comment: Without a surprise, actually. 
After "md5sum mysheet.xlsx ; ./import_xlsx.pl mysheet.xlsx: 

* On the "bad" computer: 
    86215e87b22f0b7eb72db6580772d840  
    $VAR1 = bless( {
        'Type' => 'Date',
        'Format' => 'm-d-yy',
        'Val' => '42373',
        '_Value' => '1-4-16'
    }, 'Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell' );

* On the "good" one: 
    86215e87b22f0b7eb72db6580772d840
    $VAR1 = bless( {
        'Format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        'Val' => '2016-01-04',
        '_Value' => '2016-01-04',
        'Type' => 'Date'
    }, 'Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell' );

Answer (score 1):

With the benefit of hindsight, I think its worth revisiting this to produce a succinct answer for those who come across this problem in the future.

The original question was how could a perl script produce two different results when the excel data file fed into it is identical (which was confirmed with MD5 checksums).  As programmers, our focus tends to be on the scripts we write and the data that goes into them.  What slips to the back of the mind is the myriad of ways that perl itself can be installed and configured.

The three things that should assist in determining where the difference between two installs lie are;

(1) Use strawberry perl on a stick as described above to take the environment out of the equation and thereby (if the problem "disappears") confirm that the problem is something to do with the environment.

(2) Use `Data::Dumper` liberally throughout to find where the flow of execution "forks."

(3) Compare the output of `perl -V` (note capital V) to find out if there are differences in how the respective perls were built and configured.

Comment: I included results of the discovery in the comment under my original post: cpan module distributed as rpm was to be blamed. When I replaced it with the module compiled locally, the problem disappeared. 

Should I have included it as an answer instead of the comment?

Comment: I think so - not only stating what it was in this instance, but also summarizing what would have helped given what you know now (ie with the hindsight).  That's what I was trying to do - but I also wanted to get the "-V" on the board because I think that would have helped.  Having said all that, I've only been here a couple of weeks, so what would I know... :-)